# He as well as I is/am/are brave

Tags: sentence-construction, subject-verb-agreement

1. He as well as I is brave.
2. He as well as I am brave.
3. He as well as I are brave.

I think that 1 is correct. But I am confused about why 2 and 3 are not correct. What is the rule here?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is: **He is brave.** The subject is "he," so the conjugated form of `to be` is `is`. The parenthetical clause "as well as I" is inserted into the sentence, but this does not change what the subject is, so it does not change the form of the verb either.

But this is an awkward phrasing. I would prefer "He is brave, as am I" or "He and I are both brave" (in this case the subject is "He and I," which is plural, so the conjugated form of `to be` is `are`).